# Using VLOOKUP to match 2 cells sheet2 to sheet1 and return the 3rd cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have been using `VLOOKUP()` to populate worksheets with Inventories, however I'm stuck with an issue where one column has the same value in multiple cells, I need to match 2 cells from sheet 2 with sheet 1 and have it return the 3rd cell from sheet 1 into sheet 2.

I'm working with about 350 rows in both sheets, and in some cells the same/different values repeat it self hence needing it to match with 2 cells in the same row.

This is the formula I currently use:

```vb
=VLOOKUP(A1&L1,'Sheet1'!$A$1:$E$351,3,FALSE)
```

I'm expecting it to return the value that's in the 3rd column on sheet 1 in the row that matched the values of Cell A1 and L1 in sheet 2. and the same going on A2 & L2 then A3 & L3 and so forth.

Comment: Your formula is built wrong as you should type `AND(A1;L1)` instead of your `A1&L1`. Haven't tried much further as this is a major mistake. 
Depending on your local format you may need `AND(A1,L1)` instead the one above with the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this task is to use a helper column

Go to Sheet one where the data table is, insert a column at the starting point of data e.g your Data set starting in SHEET1 from the column A. so insert new column in A
use this formula in A1

```
=CONCATENATE(B1,C1,D1,E1,F1) Press Enter, Drag the formula down to A351
```

now go to sheet2 and use this formula in the result cell

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&L1,'Sheet1'!$A$1:$F$351,4,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have values in Column A of your 'Sheet1' that are the equal to to concatenation of your values in Columns A and L in 'Sheet2', the formula will not work.

Instead, I'd try `FILTER` if you have the newest version of Excel. Something like:

```
=FILTER('Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$351, 
(('Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$351=A1)*('Sheet1'!$L$1:$L$351=L1)))
```

Another option is `INDEX`. Something like:

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$351, 
MATCH(A1&L1, 'Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$351&'Sheet1'!$L$1:$L$351,0),
3)
```

Comment: I didn't know about this formula. thank you sharing :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and very helpful information, unfortunately that does not solve my problem.

Let me try and give a better example of

Sheet 2 A1 = Street Name XYZ B1 = Suburb ABC

Sheet 1 C13 = Street Name XYZ D13 = Suburb ABC

If Cells A1 and B1 in sheet 2 matches any row in Sheet 1 then it needs to copy the value from Sheet 1 Cell A13 in the row where A1 and B1 matched, in this case A1 and B1 matched C13 and D13 in sheet 1, now it needs to show the value of A13 in Sheet 2?

My head hurts haha

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your datasheets? Of course after removing sensitive data.